# Is it good practice to replace all table view with collection view?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

As we already know,

> collection view (UICollectionView), new in iOS 6, is a UIScrollView
>   subclass that generalizes the notion of a UITableView. So I consider
>   replace all my UITableView with UICollectionView.

In my opinion, using ONLY collection view is good (I mean to avoid duplication and inconsistence)

1. collection view has all the benefit of table view, plus the power to custom layout
2. It is not consistent to keep some `UITableViewCell` subclasses and
   some `UICollectionViewCell` subclasses, we should use
   `UICollectionViewCell` subclasses only

So is it good practice to replace all table views with collection view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would beg to differ from the point that " It is good practice to replace all table views with collection view". There are number of good reasons why we still need tableViews at some point in our apps. With very little knowldge, let me try to list them down here

1. TableView is preferred when data to be presented contains mostly textual content, while collection view would be better for graphical/multimedia content.
2. While providing InApp settings, I'd opt for tableView rather than collectionView, as it would be symmetrical to default settings given in device.
3. If I have to create simple UI, with some single column data in scrolling interface, I'd go for tableView, as it would be easy to implement.

Comment: UITableView is better in many ways.

Comment: @Xeieshan Your contribution would be appreciated to support your statement. feel free to mention reasons ..:)

Answer (score 1):

Along with the answers above, it is worthy to note that UICollectionView doesn't have the sticky section header views that UITableView does. This is going to make your table-like collection views not look like genuine counterpart. This would be particularly annoying if you have large sections.

Comment: We now have [CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout)

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to have is a table view, there's no reason to change it just because something else exists that technically works. A `UICollectionView` would be useful when what you want can't be easily done with a `UITableView`.